# Update latitude and longitude Leaflet Vue js

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

```
const getAgenApi = () => {
  this.longitudeNow = parseFloat(106.105104103);
  this.latitudeNow = parseFloat(-123.123);

  // other code...
};

mymap.on("geosearch/showlocation", function (result) {
  console.log(result);
  // Remove marker
  marke.forEach(function (maker) {
    mymap.removeLayer(maker);
  });

  this.longitudeNow = result.location.x;
  this.latitudeNow = result.location.y;
  // Draw updated locations!
  GetAgenApi();
});
```

Can anyone fix this code to update the latitude and longitude?

Comment: In both cases where you are assigning the longitude and latitude your variables are out of scope.  You can find out more on variable scopes and Lexical Environment at  [https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/variable-scope.html](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/variable-scope.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pi and Mash wrote in comment, your variables are out of scope.

You have to convert `mymap.on` callback to use arrow function:

```
mymap.on("geosearch/showlocation", (result) => {
  // Now this.longitudeNow points valid variable 
  this.longitudeNow = result.location.x;
  // ...
});
```